# EJB Transaction problems

Tags: transactions, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I have an EJB which purpose is to copy users from another system to mine, by either creating the user if missing, or updating the existing user that has the same id. Three methods are used:

```
@Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "0", persistent = false)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public void timer(){
    updateUserDB();
    // Some other stuff
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public void updateUserDB(boolean delta) {
    // Find users in external system
    for(every user in the external system) {
        createUser(externalUser);
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void createUser(User externalUser) {
    try{
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();
        return;
    }catch(Exception e){} // Logs
    em.clear(); // Make sure the user is removed from the persistence context (or it will try to add it again if an error occured at the next flush
    context.setRollbackOnly(); // Rollback if error occured
```

The scenario I'm looking for is to persist all users, if an error occured, I want to log this and rollback that single persist and then continue with the rest of the users. So `REQUIRES_NEW` on `createUser()` makes sense. In otherwords, there should be x number of transactions started in total, where x is the number of users.

**Problem**

Documentation of EJB only covers if a method being called should start a transaction or not, but how should I annotate the calling ("client") methods; `timer()` and `updateUserDB` correctly? NOT_SUPPORTS and SUPPORTS causes the ejb to throw a `TransactionRequiredException` when reaching `em.persist(user)` inside `createUser()`, which I think makes no sense because `createUser()` should be allowed to start a new transaction when called from a SUPPORTS method. If I annotate the calling methods with REQUIRED, no users are persisted at all, it seems like the rollback affects a larger transaction then, instead of the small (per user) transaction.

**How should these three methods be annotated to get the desired effect?**

**Edit**
Setting both calling methods to Required makes JTA not throw an exception, but the transaction is rolled back every time for some reason, even if I remove `context.setRollbackOnly()`.